# cannot READ struct binary file twice using while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myStruct),sizeof(STRUCT)))

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles, fstream, reinterpret-cast

Cannot read from struct binary file twice. I want to open and read a binary file of structs. Comments in code explain. The first loop works but the second loop is bypassed completely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> // this library stored the std::setw

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\n Hello world!" << endl;

struct STRUCT{
    int x;
    int y;
};
STRUCT myStruct;

fstream file;
file.open("c:read.dat",std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myStruct),sizeof(STRUCT))){
        cout << "\n" << setw(14) << "t1" << setw(14) << "t1";// test inside loop
        cout << "\n" << setw(14) << myStruct.x << setw(14) << myStruct.y ;
        };
// Above will work and print
file.clear(); // **This worked. Thank you.**
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
file.seekp(0, ios::beg);   
// below printed after inserting file.clear() before file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
while(file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myStruct),sizeof(STRUCT))){
        cout << "\n" << setw(14) << "q" << setw(14) << "q";// test inside loop
        cout << "\n" << setw(14) << myStruct.x << setw(14) << myStruct.y ;
        };
cout << "\n The End";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `file.seekg()` doesn't reset the fail state. Look for how to use `file.clear()`.

Comment: Now please read the manual [`std::basic_istream::seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) carefully.

Comment: what is the different: f1.seekp(-flag,ios::cur); f1.write((char*)&z,sizeof(z)); and int w = sizeof(ee)/2;f1.seekp(-w,ios::cur);f1.seekg(-w,ios::cur); f1.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&z),sizeof(z)); Why reinterpret_cast version requires moving the seekp by size/2 ?